# Necessary and suficient condition for a sequence of $L^2([0,1])$ to be a basis.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be an orthonormal set in the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$ over the reals. Show that $\{f_n\}$ is a basis if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int _{[0,x]}f_n(t)dt=x, \forall x\in [0,1]$

I begun with the assumption that $\{f_n\}$ is a basis and want to prove the above equality. Since the functions $\chi _{[0,x]}\in L^2([0,1])$ for every $x\in [0,1]$, by Parseval's identity we get that $\sum (\int_{[0,x]}f_n(t)dt)^2=x, \forall x\in [0,1]$. Is there a mistake with the exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parseval's identity states that

$$ \|g\|^2 = \sum_n\langle g, f_n\rangle^2 $$

Therefore

$$ x= \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,x}^2(s)\, ds = \sum_n\bigg(\int_{[0,x]} f_n(s)\, ds\bigg)^2  $$

Which is not the equality you have at hand.

Take the Haar basis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) and consider

$$g = \chi_{[0,1]}  $$

$$g = \frac{f_1 + f_0}{2}  + \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{ f_0 - f_1  }{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}f_3\bigg) = \frac{3}{4} f_0 + \frac{1}{4}f_1  + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}f_3  $$

$$ \frac{3}{4} =  \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)^2  + \bigg(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2  $$

But if you compute

$$\sum_n\int_{[0,x]} f_n = \langle g , f_n \rangle = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}  \neq \frac{3}{4}$$

So yes, the exercise is wrong

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I was also thinking that the right hand side of the equality that we are trying to prove is always nonnegative while i think there is no reason for the left hand side to be nonnegative.

Comment: If we assume the exercise would be to prove that $\{f_n\}$ is a basis if and only if $\sum (\int_{[0,1]}f_n(t)dt)^2$, would it be correct, or the square breaks the reverse implication, since linearity is not yew preserved?

Comment: You mean  $\{f_n\}$ is a basis if and only if $x= \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,x}^2(s)\, ds = \sum_n\bigg(\int_{[0,x]} f_n(s)\, ds\bigg)^2$?

Comment: Yes i was wondering if there is only a typo with the exercise or if it is completely wrong.